# How do I extract variables from dynamic array and create an update query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

I have a form that is dynamically created based off multiple mysql tables. This form sends to an external page for processing.

this means that my $_POST data will always be different. I need to extract the post array, strip it down and create a query.

here's the print_r of the Posted array:

```
Array ( [userid] => 1 [modid1] => on [fid1] => on [fid3] => on [fid5] => on [fid7] => on [fid8] => on [modid3] => on )
```

as you can see I have three parts to this userid, modid, and fid. the catch is, the only way I could pass the id's I need is to name the fields that. So each modid and fid are rows in the db. the number after that is the id that needs updating, and of course "on" is from the check box.

so end result would be something like:

to give a better idea here's how I would write the query normally

for modid1:
UPDATE table SET var = var WHERE modid = 1

for fid1
UPDATE table SET var = var WHERE fid = 1

heres the code that generated this array:

```
<form id="ajaxsubmit" method="post" action="modules/users/updaterights.php">
<?php
$modsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modules")or die("Mod failed " .mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($modsql))
{
echo '<div class="rights">';
echo "<ul>";
$userid = safe($_POST['user']);
$id = $row['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modpermissions WHERE userid = '$userid' AND modid =     '$id'")or die("Mod died " .mysql_error());
$sql2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$modper = $sql2['modpermission'];
    if($modper == 1){
        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="modid'.$row["id"].'" checked>&nbsp;  <b>'.$row["name"].'</b></li>';
    }
    if($modper == 0){
        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="modid'.$row["id"].'">&nbsp;<b>'.$row["name"].'</b></li>';
    }
if($row['features'] == 1)
{
    echo "<ul>";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM features WHERE modid = '$id'")or die("Features  loop failed " .mysql_error());
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $userid2 = safe($_POST['user']);
        $id2 = $row2['id'];
        $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fpermissions WHERE userid = '$userid2' AND  fid = '$id2'")or die("features died " .mysql_error());
        $sql4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3);
        $fper = $sql4['fpermission'];
            if($fper == 1){
                echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="fid'.$row2["id"].'"  checked>&nbsp;'.$row2['feature'].'</li>';
            }
            if($fper == 0){
                echo '<li><input type="checkbox"  name="fid'.$row2["id"].'">&nbsp;'.$row2['feature'].'</li>';
            }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo '</div>';
}
?>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> <input type="reset"  class="reset" value="Reset Form"> </p>
</form>
```

its a mess I know, im learning. If someone can understand my question and point me in the right direction to accomplish what Im attempting I would be grateful.

Comment: Remember that a check box value will not be returned when the check box is not selected. Hence your code can update records when the check box is selected, but can't turn them off when unselected.

Comment: Indeed. I thought that approach would be the best option. However I think it complicated matters. I have since changed them to radios and am trying to get my code to work using those instead. I have made it much further with that method as well as the others you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to store the old value as well as having the check box (using a hidden field).

I would also suggest as a minimum using a fixed character as a delimeter in your field names so you can explode the field name to easy get the part that is the id.

Also consider using joins  rather than looping around one result, and for each one doing another query.

Your output script would look something like this:-

```
<form id="ajaxsubmit" method="post" action="modules/users/updaterights.php">
<?php
$userid = safe($_POST['user']);
$modsql = mysql_query("SELECT modules.id, modules.features, modules.name, modpermissions.modpermission 
                        FROM modules
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN modpermissions
                        ON modules.id = modpermissions.modid
                        AND modpermissions.userid = '$userid'")or die("Mod failed " .mysql_error());
$PrevModuleId = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($modsql))
{
    if ($PrevModuleId != $row['id'])
    {
        if ($PrevModuleId != 0)
        {
            echo "</ul>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="rights">';
        echo "<ul>";
        $PrevModuleId = $row['id'];
    }
    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="modid_'.$row["id"].'" '.(($row['modpermission'] == 1) ? "checked='checked'" : "").'><input type="hidden" name="modid_old_'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row['modpermission'].'">&nbsp;  <b>'.$row["name"].'</b></li>';
    if($row['features'] == 1)
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT features.id, features.feature, fpermissions.fpermission 
                            FROM features 
                            INNER JOIN fpermissions 
                            ON features.id = fpermissions.fid
                            AND fpermissions.userid = $userid
                            WHERE modid = '$id'")or die("Features  loop failed " .mysql_error());
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="fid_'.$row2["id"].'"  '.(($row2['fpermission'] == 1) ? "checked='checked'" : "").'><input type="hidden" name="fid_old_'.$row2["id"].'"  value="'.$row2['fpermission'].'">&nbsp;'.$row2['feature'].'</li>';
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
if ($PrevModuleId != 0)
{
    echo "</ul>";
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="button"> <input type="reset"  class="reset" value="Reset Form"> </p>
</form>
```

You can then loop through each entry on the $_POST array, explode the key based on the _ character, check when the values have changed and if needs be do an update Or possibly you can use an INSERT instead, but using ON DUPLICATE KEY update type syntax (this way you can update many rows with different values easily).

Note you also need to put the userid value somewhere in your form (probably as another hidden field) so you have the value to process with the updates.

Comment: Kickstart, Thank you for your suggestions. I will use them to the best of my ability. that being said. I gave your code a shot and it worked with one issue. Instead of looping through all the rows in the tables it only displayed the ones that had to be checked. I attempted to track down the problem with it, but was unable to. That being said I have used elements of the code you provided and am attempting a different simpler approach to my problem.

Comment: Loop around the hidden fields, and for each one of those check for the existence of the radio button / check box. If found you know it is set, but if not found you know it isn't set.